# how to get element class in template kendo ui using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-grid

i have obstacle about get element class using jquery.
this is my code:

```
                        {
                        template: "<a class='task editGroupUser' onclick='goToEdit(this)'><i class='fa fa-pencil'>"+
                                "</i>&nbsp &nbsp</a><a class='task removeGroupUser' onclick='deleteGroupUser(this)'><i class='fa fa-trash'>"+
                                "</i>&nbsp &nbsp</a><a class='task manageMember' onclick='goToEditMember(this)'>Edit Member</a>",
                        title: "Action"
                    }
```

and than so gol i wish get element class that using task.

in this my code jQuery that i do

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {

        console.log($(".task"));



    });
</script>
```

and than its output my console

`[prevObject: b.fn.b.init[1], context: document, selector: ".task"]`

Question: how can i get children using jQuery.

Comment: Use `.children()`, `$('.task').children()`

Comment: i already try '$('.task').children()', but still output in my console [prevObject: b.fn.b.init[1], context: document, selector: ".task"], i wish get object this example: [a.task.addUser, a.task.addTenant, prevObject: b.fn.b.init[1], context: document, selector: ".task"]

Comment: Do you want a list of the `anchor` tags? Do you want a list of everything with the `.task` class?  What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery constructor accepts a 2nd parameter called context which can be used to override the context of the selection.

```
jQuery("img", this);
```

Which is the same as using `.find()` like this:

```
jQuery(this).find("img");
```

If the imgs you desire are only direct descendants of the clicked element, you can also use `.children():`

```
jQuery(this).children("img");
```